# Forcing client to use un-cached resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, caching, browser-cache, cache-control

I have an Angular JS app that Im running a production environment and make deployments that include new features on a fairly regular basis.

My app has a sizable number of returning users and since the app is essentially just a JS file, the JS running on their device is often a cached version. Sometimes this is a problem because the new features may not be backwards compatible.

One method I'm aware of to force browsers to download a fresh version of a resource is to place random URL parameters in the src.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css"> <!-- cached -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css?8f834giywe"> <!-- uncached -->
```

But for some reason, this doesnt work in my angular app.

```
<script src="./app/js/app.min.js"></script> <!-- cached -->
<script src="./app/js/app.min.js?43gt4gf342"></script> <!-- broken -->
```

The app loads (not a server-level issue) but immediately breaks.

[image]

Can anyone think of any reason why this would not work?

Any there any other options to force a client to download a fresh copy or a resource rather than using a cached version?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding to the Header section of the HTML the following line:

```
<meta http-equiv="CACHE-CONTROL" content="NO-CACHE">
```

This worked for me without the need to play with URLs.